# Can't fetch realtime data in a chart in react.Js using Chart.Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

please help me to find the error, I need to show a chart in real time (I'm using 'time' instead of 'realtime' for x because it doesn't work) and y=Math.random().
I didn' get errors but only this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUMud.png)

and here is the code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao0uM.png)

```
var config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Dataset 1 (linear interpolation)',
      backgroundColor: color(chartColors.red).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
      borderColor: chartColors.red,
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0,
      borderDash: [8, 4],
      data: []
    }, {
      label: 'Dataset 2 (cubic interpolation)',
      backgroundColor: color(chartColors.blue).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
      borderColor: chartColors.blue,
      fill: false,
      cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone',
      data: []
    }]
  },

  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Data labels plugin sample'
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: {
        type: 'time',
        realtime: {
          duration: 20000,
          refresh: 1000,
          delay: 2000,
          onRefresh: onRefresh
        }
      },
      yAxes: {
        type: 'linear',
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'value'
        },
      }
    }
  }
};


function Streaming() {

  return (
    <div className="chart">
      <Line {...config} />
    </div>
  );
}


export default Streaming
```

Comment: Isn't the `y: Math.random` in your picture missing ()?

Comment: yes, but even when I add it,I always get the same results